# Python:Rest server

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x, rest

Error giving by python server

> Second simultaneous read on fileno 3 detected. Unless you really know
>   what you're doing, make sure that only one greenthread can read any
>   particular socket. Consider using a pools.Pool. If you do know what
>   you're doing and want to disable this error, call
>   eventlet.debug.hub_prevent_multiple_readers(False) - MY THREAD=; THAT
>   THREAD=FdListener('read', 3, , )

fucntion:

```
 try:                                                           
                fd.sendto(string_to_send,"/tmp/serversocket")
 except Exception, e:                                           
                ERROR

 while 1:                                                       
                try:                                                   
                        data = fd.recv(struct.calcsize(format_))
                        "parsing of data received"                      


                except Exception, e:                                   
                        err = e.args[0]                                
                        if err == errno.EAGAIN or err == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                                 print 'No data available'             
                                 continue                              
                        else:                                          
                               ERROR
```

Having two functions of same functionality,
while accessing the functions simultaneously , i am getting this error .

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a mutex

```
lock = threading.RLock()
...
with lock:
    # fd stuff
```

Comment: Is this handle the requests simultaneously?

Comment: well, just put the mutex around the fd.recv so only one thread is reading at a time.  The "parsing of data received" part will be concurrent.

Comment: But I want to act these functions as asynchronously,but rlock all these are synchronous  type.